# How to run Brainscript and Python programs using CNTK 2.2?

Tags: cntk, brainscript

I installed the CNTK 2.2, python 3.5, GPU wheel file and ran some python examples. I open an anaconda3 window and try to run the brainscript examples but it can't find cntk.exe. What am I doing wrong?
Do I also have to install the Script Driven Installation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes/No. One way is to choose the script driven installation.

However, you really have to install CNTK first, no matter how. You basically can choose from these options:

- Python-only installation
- Script-driven installation
- Manual installation

For details, visit the tutorial published by Microsoft. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/Setup-CNTK-on-your-machine

Finally, I think BrainScript is supposed to be used via commandline -> cmd or PowerShell.